# Windows Server 2003 Permissions - Restricted web directory

Tags: windows, permissions, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I'm not great with windows server so not sure of the best way to describe this. I have a Windows 2003 Server box running IIS 6. I'm giving a designer FTP to a specific folder on the root and allowing read/write access. This is so they can't touch the rest of the website.

However, his scripts surely would be able to? For example he could create an upload script? What's the best way to "self-contain" this folder?

Cheers,
RJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would do if possible is to remove the execute rights for that folder in IIS

```
In IIS MMC expand the website, select the folder and open the properties windows. 
On the Home Directory tab, Change the execute permissions to **NONE**
```

This would allow them to upload files (any files) but scripts in that folder will not execute/run

Hope this helps.